# Whats the revenue value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say the following scenario:

$4A + 311B  = \text{ SUM}$

Where

$4A$ contributes to $40\%$ of the total sum.

$311B$ contributes to $60\%$ of the total sum.

Question:

If we want to get the $A$ portion to be $20\%$ instead of $40\%$ of the new sum,
and $4A$ stays the same.
How many of $B$ should it be in order to make this happen?

My Approach:

Let $x$ = the old sum

$n$ = is the number of $B$ required.

$\frac{2}{10}(\frac{40}{100}x+n*\frac{60}{100}*x) = \frac{40}{100}x$

By solving the equation,

I found that $n = 829.3333333$
which is wrong, can I know what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I changed the problem sightly. Let's say that $A+B=X$. Also, we know that
$$
\frac{A}{X} = 0.4 \qquad \frac{B}{X} = 0.6
$$
Now, if we take another sum to be $Y$ and set $A+kB = Y$, and additionally we want
$$
\frac{A}{Y} = 0.2 \qquad \frac{kB}{Y} = 0.8
$$
Now we have some equations to play with. Comparing the two equations with $A$, we get
$$
A = 0.4X = 0.2Y \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Y = 2X
$$
Then the same for $B$ ...
$$
B = 0.6X = \frac{0.8Y}{k}
$$
Perhaps you can continue from here?

Comment: @MattiP. I believe you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll simplify the problem and make the solution as concise as I can. Let's first get rid of the numerical constants and just say that we have a sum
$$
A + B = X
$$
It is given that $B=0.6X$ and $A=0.4X$. Then we want a new sum so that $A$ is equal to $0.2$ times the right-hand side; it's quite clear that in the new equation, the right-hand side should be equal to $2X$. Therefore, we have the following new sum:
$$
A+kB = 2X
$$
where $k$ is some scaling constant. Now, we want the part $kB$ to be equal to $0.8$ times the right-hand side, or
$$
kB = 0.8\cdot 2X
$$
Earlier, we learned that $B=0.6X$. Let's plug that in and we get
$$
k \cdot 0.6X = 0.8 \cdot 2X
$$
As long as $X\neq 0$, we get $k = \frac{0.8\cdot 2}{0.6}= \frac{8}{3}$.

Comment: yes, 8/3*311 = 829.3333333. I actually have the correct answer. I used the wrong value for A and B while checking (A != 40% of the total sum), and that leads to my confusion. Kudos for understanding my question and simplifying it, although I explain it quite badly.